# Install OrientDB with source code sucessfully,but no release directory

Tags: orientdb

After I have installed orientdb with source code sucessfully,but no release directory in a level! I want to know how to fix the problem

Comment: What command did you use to install orientdb with source code ?

Comment: cd orientdb;mvn clean install;    I can see the mvn result:Build Success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc about installation from sources is updated:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Installation.html#source-code-installation

the old releases directory isn't created anymore by maven.

Answer (score 1):

With Maven when you use the command "mvn clean install" from your folder with the source code, the folder with your version of OrientDb will be created under the following path rootfolder/distrubution/target
The folder "releases" isn't created but with Maven, for example, will be created the folder orientdb-community.2.1.10-snapshot.dir